# How do you explain the use of "pas" in the phrase "n’a pas surgi de nulle part"?

Tags: négation

> Toutefois, l’administration Trump **n**’a **pas** surgi de **nulle** part. C’est l’aboutissement d’un processus prolongé, avec notamment le vol des élections de 2000.
>
> {vs}: Toutefois, l’administration Trump **n**’a surgi de **nulle** part.

I intuitively grasp that the omission of "pas" sounds odd here in the light of the meaning of the sentence, but I cannot offer a rationale for using "pas" despite the presence of the negative word "nulle" that usually does not allow the addition of "pas".

I assume this is not about a double negation at work here.

---

> {incorrect: e.g.}: Elle ne pouvait **pas** se cacher nulle part.

Comment: If you want to stretch your understanding of double negation a bit, try « Rien n'existe pas » (can't remember where I first saw it but [here](http://forums.futura-sciences.com/astronomie-astrophysique/587048-rien.html)'s one usage), a modern take on [the Victor Hugo quote](http://dicocitations.lemonde.fr/citations/citation-93622.php). :)

Comment: @LukeSawczak Can you take a look at my comment below? Now I think  this is not about a double negation, after all. If we replace « de nulle part » with « subitement », it all seems straightforward enough.

Comment: I guess it's fair to avoid calling it"double negation if we mean only verbal negation. (It's true that *nulle part* can't replace *pas*.) But in a looser usage meaning two "negative polarity" items that end up with a positive meaning...

Answer (score 2):

There is a double negation.

> l’administration n’a pas surgi de nulle part.

means

> l'administration a surgi de quelque part.

i.e., the admistration didn't emerge out of nowhere.

Comment: Hi. How do you interpret the meaning of "Trump **n**’a surgi de **nulle** part"?

Comment: I interpret it as an non idiomatic sentence. That should be either *a surgi de nulle part* or *n'a pas surgi de nulle part*

Comment: Hi. Shouldn’t we consider the phrase « de nulle part / subitement » to have nothing to do with negation, just like « au milieu de nulle part »? « Ce n’est pas comme si Trump **avait surgi de nulle part**. »: This "si" clause is an affirmative structure through and through despite the presence of the word « nulle ». So adding « ne ... pas » to « surgir de nulle part » seems like a single negation, not a double negation, the way I see it now. I think the word « nulle » had me confused there.

Comment: I mentioned double negation because *de nulle part* is the negation of *de quelque part* like *nowhere* is the negation of *somewhere*.

Comment: I suspect "n'a surgi de nulle part" is not possible because **it's a set phrase**. *Surgir de nulle part* fonctions as a whole verb, which prevents "connecting" *nulle* and *ne* (already a somewhat literary construction in the first place) as a two-part negation. Just like you can't pull disjoin it into a relative: *la part d'où a surgi l'administration trump* is downright ungrammatical.